# How do I embed and use resource files in a C program using VS11?

Tags: c, visual-studio, embedded-resource

This is my first attempt at using a resource file. I have seen a lot of answers that apply to C# but not C. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean the method used by Sysinternals and others to carry the drivers or needed DLLs (or even the x64 version of the program itself) in the resource section of a program (e.g. Sysinternals' Process Explorer), using Microsoft Visual C you can use this code:

```
BOOL ExtractResTo(HINSTANCE Instance, LPCTSTR BinResName, LPCTSTR NewPath, LPCTSTR ResType)
{
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    HRSRC hRsrc;
    if(hRsrc = FindResource(HMODULE(Instance), BinResName, ResType))
    {
        HGLOBAL hGlob
        if(HGLOBAL hGlob = LoadResource(Instance, hRsrc))
        {
            DWORD dwResSize = SizeofResource(Instance, hRsrc);
            HANDLE hFileWrite = CreateFile(NewPath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, 0);
            if(hFileWrite != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            __try
            {
                DWORD dwSizeWritten = 0;
                bResult = (WriteFile(hFileWrite, LockResource(hGlob), dwResSize, &dwSizeWritten, NULL) && (dwSizeWritten == dwResSize));
            }
            __finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hFileWrite);
            }
        }
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

This saves the given resource (`BinResName`) of resource type (`ResType`) from the module (e.g. a DLL) `Instance` to file `NewPath`. Obviously if your C doesn't understand `__try` and `__finally` you'll have to adjust the code accordingly.

Taken from [here](http://blog.assarbad.net/20061105/redpill-getting-colorless/) (in `SIDT.rar`) and adjusted for C. The code is under the liberal BSD license according to the website.

Now if you wanted to get the pointer to the data (`ppRes`) and its size (`pwdResSize`):

```
BOOL GetResourcePointer(HINSTANCE Instance, LPCTSTR ResName, LPCTSTR ResType, LPVOID* ppRes, DWORD* pdwResSize)
{
    // Check the pointers to which we want to write
    if(ppRes && pdwResSize)
    {
        HRSRC hRsrc;
        // Find the resource ResName of type ResType in the DLL/EXE described by Instance
        if(hRsrc = FindResource((HMODULE)Instance, ResName, ResType))
        {
            HGLOBAL hGlob;
            // Make sure it's in memory ...
            if(hGlob = LoadResource(Instance, hRsrc))
            {
                // Now lock it to get a pointer
                *ppRes = LockResource(hGlob);
                // Also retrieve the size of the resource
                *pdwResSize = SizeofResource(Instance, hRsrc);
                // Return TRUE only if both succeeded
                return (*ppRes && *pdwResSize);
            }
        }
    }
    // Failure means don't use the values in *ppRes and *pdwResSize
    return FALSE;
}
```

Call like this:

```
LPVOID pResource;
DWORD pResourceSize;
if(GetResourcePointer(hInstance, _T("somename"), _T("sometype"), &pResource, &pResourceSize))
{
    // use pResource and pResourceSize
    // e.g. store into a string buffer or whatever you want to do with it ...
}
```

Note, this also works for resources with integer IDs. You can detect these by using the macro `IS_INTRESOURCE`.

The resource script, e.g. myresources.rc, itself is trivial:

```
#include <winnt.rh>
"somename" "sometype" "path\to\file\to\embed"
```

`RCDATA` instead of sometype is a reasonable choice

```
#include <winnt.rh> // for RCDATA to be known to rc.exe
"somename" RCDATA "path\to\file\to\embed"
```

... in which case you would adjust the above call to be:

```
GetResourcePointer(hInstance, _T("somename"), RT_RCDATA, &pResource, &pResourceSize)
```

---

Complete example making use of `GetResourcePointer` above. Let's say you have a pointer variable `char* buf` and you know your resource is actual text, then you need to make sure that it is zero-terminated when used as a string, that's all.

Resource script:

```
#include <winnt.rh>

"test" RCDATA "Test.txt"
```

The code accessing it

```
char* buf = NULL;
LPVOID pResource;
DWORD pResourceSize;
if(GetResourcePointer(hInstance, _T("test"), RT_RCDATA, &pResource, &pResourceSize))
{
    if(buf = calloc(pResourceSize+1, sizeof(char)))
    {
        memcpy(buf, pResource, pResourceSize);
        // Now use buf
        free(buf);
    }
}
```

---

Unless, of course you meant to simply link a `.res` file which works by passing it to the linker command line.

Comment: I simply want to have access to an xml file, text file, and ps1 file. In the C program I call on theses files. I would like to have them embedded into the exe. I am new to VS and c programming. In fact I have my first class on it next semester in college. I am just anxious to learn so I decided to write a program.

Comment: @arynhard: Well, the above function does what you want then. Let me add a little derived version that allows you to read it into a buffer instead ...

Comment: I don't know if it is worth noting, but I am not using Microsoft Visual C, I am using Visual Studio Pro 11.

Comment: @arynhard: that *is* Microsoft Visual C, or rather contains it. I was merely hinting at the fact that `__try` is not supported in all C compilers (and not the same everywhere). Also, above are the C variants, but should work for the C++ compiler, too.

Comment: I have to admit, it seems a little over my head, but I will try to figure it out. Any tutorials you might suggest that could help me understand what this code is doing exactly? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @arynhard: what exactly is unclear? ... I'll add a few comments perhaps that helps (but only to the second variant which could actually be used to implement the first).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12131/discussion-between-arynhard-and-status-access-denied)